# Java: Why method type in .class file contains return type, not only signature?

Tags: jvm, java

There is a "NameAndType" structure in the constants pool in .class file.
It is used for dynamic binding. 
All methods that class can "export" described as "signature + return type".
Like

```
"getVector()Ljava/util/Vector;"
```

That breakes my code when return type of the method in some .jar is changed, even if new type is narrower.

i.e:
I have the following code:

```
List l = some.getList();
```

External .jar contains:

```
public List getList()
```

Than external jar changes method signature to

```
public ArrayList getList().
```

And my code dies in run-time with NoSuchMethodException, because it can't find

```
getList()Ljava/util/List;
```

So, I have to **recompile** my code. 
I do not have to change it. Just recompile absolutely the same code!

That also gives ability to have two methods with *one* signature, but different return types! Compiler would not accept it, but it is possible to do it via direct opcoding.

My questions is *why*?
Why they did it?

I have only one idea: to prevent sophisticated type checking in the runtime. 
You need to look up to the hierarchy and check if there is a parent with List interface.
It takes time, and only compiler has it. JVM does not.

Am I right?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One reason may be because method overloading (as opposed to overriding) is determined at compile time. Consider the following methods:

```
public void doSomething(List util) {}

public void doSomething(ArrayList util) {}
```

And consider code:

```
doSomething(getList());
```

If Java allowed the return type to change and did not throw an exception, the method called would still be doSomething(List) until you recompiled - then it would be doSomething(ArrayList). Which would mean that working code would change behavior just for having recompiled it.