# How to have scala infer types from a java method

Tags: scala, type-inference

I am trying to consume an external Java Service API in Scala by writing a wrapper around it. Each API call has a Request class and Response class, as well as a factory method to setup a call in the underlaying java client i.e.

```
val caller = serviceClient.newDoSomething()
val request = DoSomethingRequest(...)

val response = caller.call(request)
```

where response is of type `DoSomethingResponse`.

This pattern is repeated for a bunch of different operations only varying in the names of the request/response classes and the factory method. I would like to DRY up the code and use the type inference, while noting a key observation that java method

`caller.call` is of type `Request => Response`.

Given that I've attempted the following:

```
class ServiceAPI {
    val client = Service.getDefaultClient

    def serviceCall[Req, Resp](auth: String, caller: Req => Resp)
                              (func: Req => Unit)(implicit m:Manifest[Req]):Resp = {

        val request = m.erasure.newInstance.asInstanceOf[Req]
        request.setAuth(auth)

        func(request)

        caller(request)
    }
}
```

What I would like to end up with is a consumable scala API that can be invoked like so:

```
serviceCall(myAuth, client.newEventCall.call(_)) {
    _.setFoo("foo") // On request
    _.setBar(2) // On request
}
```

I was hoping that by providing the partial function `client.newEventCall.call(_)` Scala would be able to fully infer `Req` and `Resp` from it and then properly invoke the rest.

However, this fails with:

```
error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$4) => client.newEventCall.call(x$4))
```

Obviously I can provide the type manually via:

```
serviceCall(myAuth, client.newEventCall.call(_:EventRequest)) { ... }
```

but I would like to avoid that. Any ideas?

Also bonus points if this can be further simplified.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Why method type in .class file contains return type, not only signature?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241810/java-why-method-type-in-class-file-contains-return-type-not-only-signature)